# Cannot Upload video to Facebook page using PHP but can using curl

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-graph-api, postman

I am trying to upload a video to Facebook page. I was successfull in uploading the video using a curl call via POSTMAN. Here's the curl used in POSTMAN:

```
curl -X POST \
  "https://graph-video.facebook.com/v8.0/<page_id>/videos" \
  -F "access_token=<access_token>" \
  -F "source=@/home/shubham/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb (1).mp4"
  -F "title=Sample video"
```

(In Postman, I select the file I want to upload. See attached image)[image]

However, when I tried to do the same using PHP, I am getting an error. I am using the code below to do it.

```
$ch = curl_init();

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v7.0/<page_ID>/videos');
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            $post = array(
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'source' => '@' .realpath($params['video_path']),
                'title' => $params['video_title'],
            );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);

            $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

where:  $params['video_path'] = '/home/shubham/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb (1).mp4';
$params['video_title'] = 'Sample video upload from backend';

Here is the error I am getting from Facebook:

> {"error":{"message":"There was a problem uploading your video file.
> Please try
> again.","type":"OAuthException","code":390,"error_subcode":1363030,"is_transient":true,"error_user_title":"Video
> Upload Timeout","error_user_msg":"Your video upload timed out before
> it could be completed. This is probably because of a slow network
> connection or because the video you're trying to upload is too large.
> Please try again.","fbtrace_id":"A9sy8q1MUG5UJkgNI35dfZ2"}}

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Node SDK. It only works with cURL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

if its working in postman you can create the php curl command from postman by clicking the code near to the right corner of the request